# Converting a mysql dict column using JSON_Table

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

**`Edited`**

I have a mysql table "prop" with a column "detail" that contains a dict field.

```
fnum    details
 55     '{"a":"3"},{"b":"2"},{"d":"1"}'
```

I have tried to convert this to a table.  using this

```
SELECT p.fnum, deets.*
FROM prop p
JOIN JSON_TABLE( p.details,
     '$[*]'
     COLUMNS (
              idx FOR ORDINALITY,
              a varChar(10) PATH '$.a',
              b varchar(20) PATH '$.b'
              d varchar(45) PATH '$.d',
              )
     ) deets
```

I have tried various paths including $.*.  I am expecting the following:

```
fnum   a   b   d
  55    3   2   1
```

also if I have 2 rows such as

```
fnum     details
  55     '{"a":"3"},{"b":"2"},{"d":"1"}'
  56     '{"c":"car"}'
```

should generate the following

```
fnum    a       b      d       c
  55    3       2      1       null
  56    null    null   null    car
```

Answer (score 1):

Your details data is not valid JSON, because it doesn't have `[ ]` delimiting the array.

Demo:

```
mysql> create table prop (fnum int, details json);

mysql> insert into prop select 55, '{"a":"3"},{"b":"2"},{"d":"1"}';
ERROR 3140 (22032): Invalid JSON text: "The document root must 
not be followed by other values." at position 9 in value for column
'prop.details'.

mysql> insert into prop select 55, '[{"a":"3"},{"b":"2"},{"d":"1"}]';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

It's worth using the JSON data type instead of storing JSON in a text column, because the JSON data type ensures that the document is valid JSON format. It must be valid JSON to use the JSON_TABLE() function or any other JSON function.

Also your query has some syntax mistakes with respect to commas:

```
SELECT p.fnum, deets.*
FROM prop p
JOIN JSON_TABLE( p.details,
     '$[*]'
     COLUMNS (
              idx FOR ORDINALITY,
              a varChar(10) PATH '$.a',
              b varchar(20) PATH '$.b'   <-- missing comma
              d varchar(45) PATH '$.d',  <-- extra comma
              )
     ) deets
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.  and the typo was due to me mocking it up at midnight.  I wil move to the JSON field type